# correct merge of 2 tables in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have 2 tables with the same structure:
|Word|Score|

Words is unique inside of each table. (But can be not unique for 2 tables)

I need to:

1. Add data pair from second table to first if its unique for both tables(and absent in first table);
2. update word score of first table if some pair "word/score" exist in second table (i mean: if both tables have word "standard", score is "5" for first table and "10" in second table, updated score of first table must be "15")

Example:
Table1

```
|Abstract|12|
|standard|15|
|space   |30|
```

Table2

```
|Abstract|2|
|standard|2|
|aroma   |50|
```

after update must be:

```
|Abstract|14|
|standard|17|
|space   |30|
|aroma   |50|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would execute one update and one insert, to first update the matching ones, and then insert the missing ones.

Here's a full SQLite3 script that demonstrates your problem and the results:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Word TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Score INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Word TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Score INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Abstract', 12), ('standard', 15), ('space', 30);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('Abstract', 2), ('standard', 2), ('aroma', 50);

UPDATE Table1
SET Score = Score + (SELECT SUM(Score) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Word = Table2.Word)
WHERE Word IN (SELECT Word FROM Table2);

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Word NOT IN (SELECT Word FROM Table1);

SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

Results:

```
Abstract|14
standard|17
space|30
aroma|50
```

If you want to execute the insert before the update, just insert the words with a score of 0, and then the following update will add in the scores:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT Word, 0
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Word NOT IN (SELECT Word FROM Table1);

UPDATE Table1
SET Score = Score + (SELECT SUM(Score) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Word = Table2.Word)
WHERE Word IN (SELECT Word FROM Table2);
```

Now, Sqlite has some special syntax to handle some of these cases. For instance, if `Word` is the primary key of `Table1`, you can use this variant of the insert statement:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Table1
SELECT Word, 0
FROM Table2
```